# JMeter Variable output as part of property name?

Tags: java, jmeter

So I am using JMeter 3 for some performance testing and I have just been asked to make it more dynamic...

I am using the Properties File Reader plugin, and pointing it to a file that contains entries like this -

```
DEV_SEARCH_API_URL=example.com
QA_SEARCH_API_URL=example2.com
```

Now I have a User defined variable called

```
env | ${__P(perf.environment, qa)}
```

I am then performing a HTTP request building a url like this

```
https://${login_serverName}/${env}/authentication/login
```

I am calling QA_SEARCH_API_URL like so from another UDV

```
login_serverName |  ${__P(QA_AUTHENTICATION_API_URL)}
```

And this works, but what I want to be able to do is replace the QA part of the variable with the value coming from the UDV ${env} (as this will be QA or DEV) thus making the correct call for the url from my properties file...

I have tried

```
${__P(${env}_AUTHENTICATION_API_URL)}
```

But this doesn't work and doesn't return anything, I don't believe that this isn't possible, and I am just doing something wrong...

Any help would be most appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Wild guess: using a preprocessor to set up the variable name?

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

When you're putting variables inside each other, you almost always want `evalVar`.

---

There are a couple ways to talk about variables (and properties) in JMeter.

Example Variables:

`var` | `something`     <= the variable we're going to be putting into other stuff

`something_more_stuff` | `${something_else}`     <= the variable that will be made by combining things

`something_else` | `even more stuff`     <= the variable that we're trying to get

---

Example Queries:

`${${var}_more_stuff}`      |     `${${var}_more_stuff}`

`${__V(${var}_more_stuff})}`      |     `${something_else}`

`${__eval(${var}_more_stuff})}`     |     `var_more_stuff`

`${__evalVar(${var}_more_stuff})}`     |     `even more stuff`

---

As you can see, putting "variable brackets" inside each other just doesn't work. Everything else does something slightly different, which is interesting, but not necessarily useful. When you're putting variables inside each other, you almost always want `evalVar`.

Comment: Ok, this looks like it should work, but I still can't get it working...What I am trying to do is place the value of the env variable into the start of the QA_Search_API_URL jmeter property, this seems to be where the issue is, as using evalVar just created a URL with "https://qa_AUTHENTICATION_API_URL/qa/" and that is right, but it didn't get turned into the correct property and read in from the file, it just printed the "created property entry in my url"

Comment: Is it possible to set that as a variable and not a property? Perhaps in `User Defined Variables`?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, just use [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V). As per documentation:

> For example, if one has variables **A1,A2** and **N=1**:
>
> - **${A1}** - works OK
> - **${A${N}}** - does not work (nested variable reference)
> - **${__V(A${N})}** - works OK. **A${N}** becomes **A1**, and the **__V** function returns the value of A1

1. If `env` is a JMeter Variable:

   ```
   ${__V(${env}_AUTHENTICATION_API_URL)}
   ```
2. If `env` is a JMeter Property:

   ```
   ${__V(${__P(env,)}_AUTHENTICATION_API_URL)}
   ```

More information and hints: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)

Comment: Ok, this looks like it should work, but I still can't get it working...What I am trying to do is place the value of the env variable into the start of the QA_Search_API_URL jmeter property, this seems to be where the issue is, as using evalVar just created a URL with "https://qa_AUTHENTICATION_API_URL/qa/" and that is right, but it didn't get turned into the correct property and read in from the file, it just printed the "created property entry in my url"

Answer (score 1):

${__groovy(props.get(vars.get("env") + "_AUTHENTICATION_API_URL"))}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!